# Django REST API: Queryset with arguments

Tags: django-rest-framework

folks: I am trying to get the details of an entry in the database table through Django REST Framework with "url arguments" I am using the following code to get the value of "symbol" parameter however, I am getting the runtime error on the command line related to `base_name`. Here is the detail of my code:

```
class ticker_detail_full_view(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ticker_detail_full

    def get_queryset(self):
        ticker = self.kwargs['symbol']
        return ticker.objects.filter(symbol = ticker)
```

url: http://localhost:8000/qres/ticker_detail_full/?symbol=AMZN

I am getting the following error on the Django command-line:

```
router.register('ticker_detail_full', views.ticker_detail_full_view)
```

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py",
>   line 82, in register
>       base_name = self.get_default_base_name(viewset)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/routers.py",
>   line 161, in get_default_base_name
>       assert queryset is not None, '`base_name` argument not specified, and could ' \
>
> AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not
>   automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have
>   a `.queryset` attribute.

Comment: try this `router.register('ticker_detail_full', views.ticker_detail_full_view, base_name='ticker-detail-full')`

Comment: yaah thanks... it worked by adding the 'base_name' parameter explicitly